# How do I return multiple parameters one as an interface and other as a variable from a function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a constant

```
const STATUS= {status: {code: 200 }};
```

and the function is supposed to return an interface named student

```
export interface STUDENT
{
  ID?:number;
  NAME?:string
}
```

goal is to return the result as

```
return [STATUS,this.student_info as STUDENT]
```

When I use the above return statement an error is arising that "Conversion of type any[] to Student may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other"
P.S. this.student_info is previously populated by fetching data from SQL table

Comment: Create a type for `STATUS` and set the return type of the function to `[STATUS_TYPE, STUDENT]`

Comment: export interface DataStatus {
    status?: string; //200; 
    error?: any;
}---I have this code.How do I integrate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a type for `STATUS` and set the return type of the function to `[STATUS_TYPE, STUDENT]`

```
interface STATUS_TYPE {status: {code: 200; };};
const STATUS: STATUS_TYPE = {status: {code: 200 }};

export interface STUDENT
{
  ID?:number;
  NAME?:string
}

export class C {
  student_info?: STUDENT;
  f(): [STATUS_TYPE, STUDENT] {
    return [STATUS,this.student_info as STUDENT]
  }
}
```

Comment: my function is an async one and I get an error that it is not a valid ES5/ES6 format

Comment: I have now created an interface export interface Status {
    status:{code: 200}
    error:{code:404};
}.....now need to return status code with data for data found and status code alone for data doesn't exist

Comment: @kameswari There is no async function in your question. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the input jabaa..I used let Status={code:200}
            return [Status,this.student as StudentDataResult]...it worked